# How do to make Chrome Extension devtools panel support (cmd+f) find

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I have a chrome extension that returns a lot of data in it's devtools panel. I'd like to make it searchable using cmd/ctrl+f which Chrome already pops up a find panel for, but doesn't seem to do anything.
How do I make it so the existing find window supports it?

I've tried googling around for this, unfortunately, I find there to be little to no good documentation for chrome extensions out there, only what Google puts out, which often doesn't contain examples. I've tried to look at what other extensions do, the Vue chrome extension just substitutes their own search tool.

Currently, the find window shows up when you hit cmd+f but does nothing useful.
[image: screenshot of find window in dev tools]

Comment: The built-in panel only searches what it knows about.

Comment: @wOxxOm
understood but is there a way to make it so it DOES know about it?

Otherwise it seems like a bug for the find tool to appear below extension added devtools panels

Comment: You'll need to change the source code of Chrome/Chromium.

Comment: if that's the case then the fact the find panel shows up at all is a bug. Which seems pretty odd.